# Wrapper for dynamically cache HTTP URLs using service worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have an app that runs service worker. I'm using sw-toolbox library for dynamic caching of URLs, but I want to create wrapper over sw-toolbox that provides getters and setters to my application for URL caching.

As service worker runs in different thread and my application running in main thread, so just wondering how to create a wrapper in Javascript through which my application can communicate with service worker and cache resources on-demand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache), [`Cache API/interface`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) is exposed to windowed scopes as well as workers.

> You don't have to use it in conjunction with service workers, even
>   thought it is defined in the service worker spec.

Comment: In Angular 5 (at least) the Cache API is not usable because Angular replaces the browsers native Promise with its ZoneAwarePromise, what leads to an error. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49014332/angular-5-with-cachestorage)
In this case you need another context for accessing the API like an iframe (as described in my workaround) or maybe communication with the service worker to make it do the caching.

Answer (score 1):

So far the `Cache` api is available from content, that means you can use it directly from your Javascript code, no need to run in the Service Worker.

Check this thread to find the resolution: https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/issues/698 You will be able to use caches from the window object.

Meaning you have all range of Cache methods to play with the content: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache

Just another reminder, from Chrome 46, you will be able to store stuff just in secured origins.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how your worker caches data, it it just uses the standard "`Cache`" API than you can just query `cache` object which is attached to global scope.

In this particular case [`Cache.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/match) is your friend.