# Angular 5 with CacheStorage

Tags: angular, caching, promise

im trying to use CacheStorage's promises in Angular 5 like in the docs :

```
let test = caches.open('test');
    test.then((result : Cache) => {
      result.add('/test.png')
    })
```

but i got :

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: the given value is not a Promise
```

I tryed switching from es5 to es6 in the ts file. But same problem

thanks

Comment: Use `mergeMap` or `concatMap` instead of `map()`

Comment: didnt work. i updated my post with a simple Promises. But same problem.

Comment: What does `value` point to? Is it `result` or `test`?

Comment: result.add('/test.png') is supposed to return a Promise, but i get the type error.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in one of my projects. I wanted my application to store some assets in the `CacheStorage`.

My code looked something like this:

```
window.caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
  .then(cache => cache.addAll(resources))
  .catch(err => console.log('error while caching', err));
```

I got the same Error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: the given value is not a Promise
```

While searching for the problem I found out that Angular is replacing the browser's global `Promise` implementation by it's own `ZoneAwarePromise` to keep track of promises. Unfortunately the `CacheStorage` somehow expects a native `Promise` instead of Angular's `ZoneAwarePromise` and throws an error.

I tried to get around this problem by storing the `ZoneAwarePromise` temporarily and reset it with the original `Promise`. This turned out to be tricky, resulting in me giving up to exchange back the implementation.

I found two suitable **workarounds** for this.

### Service Worker <=> Client Communication

For my second (and I think better) **workaround** I open a channel for *client <=> service worker* communication and let the service worker do the dynamic caching.

1. Implement the `message` event listener in the service worker.

   The service worker will listen to the `message` event to receive and cache a list of urls from the client.

   ```
   self.addEventListener('message', event => {
     const urls = event.data;

     if (!urls) {
       event.waitUntil(Promise.reject('nothing to cache'));
       event.ports[0].postMessage(false);
     }
     else {
       event.waitUntil(
         caches.open(version)
           .then(cache => cache.addAll(urls))
           .then(self.skipWaiting())
           .then(() => console.log('dynamic urls cached'))
       );
       event.ports[0].postMessage(true);
     }
   });
   ```
2. Add caching for new urls to the client.

   This submits a message to the service worker with the list of urls as payload.

   ```
   function addToCache(urls: string[]): Promise<any> {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       let messageChannel = new MessageChannel();
       messageChannel.port1.onmessage = function(event) {
         if (event.data.error) reject(event.data.error);
         else resolve(event.data);
       };

       if (!navigator.serviceWorker.controller) reject('no service worker contoller found')
       else navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage(urls, [messageChannel.port2]);
     });
   }
   ```
3. Make sure the service worker is active for caching.

   I use the `controllerchange` event in the client to trigger re-caching if a new service worker is taking control. (see: [service worker lifecycle documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle)).

   ```
   const resources = ['some/url/to/cache.png', 'another/url/to/cache.css']

   navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', () => 
     addToCache(resources)
       .then(data => console.log('urls cached', data))
       .catch(err => console.log('error while caching', err))
   );
   ```

### Invisible `iframe`

My first **workaround** for this problem is really just a hack but it works for now.

```
const hiddenFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
hiddenFrame.style.display = 'none';
document.documentElement.appendChild(hiddenFrame);

hiddenFrame.contentWindow.caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
  .then(cache => cache.addAll(resources))
  .then(() => document.documentElement.removeChild(hiddenFrame))
  .catch(err => console.log('error while caching', err));
```

What I'm doing here:

I create a hidden `iframe` and append it to my document. Inside the `iframe` Angular is not running and so there is the native `Promise` implementation present. Then I access the cache from the iframe's `contentWindow` object. After successful caching I remove the `iframe`.

I'm still looking for a better solution.

My next try is to send a message to a service worker and let it trigger the caching of the resources. The service worker has no angular running either.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to miss -

1) **CacheStorage API** (or **Cache API**) are only available on localhost and HTTP/2.
2) For purists reason, prefer to use `window.caches.open(CACHE_NAME)` as `caches` is a singleton instance present in `window` object.