# Angular 6 cache.addAll() not working with zonejs

Tags: angular, typescript, zonejs, cachestorage

I'm trying to add files to the Cache storage in an angular 6 cli project but keep getting errors because of zonejs and I can't find out why. The code below works fine if I run in in a typescript project with no other code. The files are added to the cache so the function is executed but then it throws an error.

```
caches.open('assets').then((cache) => {
    return cache.add('image.png');
});
```

If I run the same code in my angular project I get the error

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: the given value is not a Promise
>   TypeError: the given value is not a Promise

See [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vun9xq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) to reproduce the error. When you click the sync button the given files are added to the cache storage and then the error is thrown.

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49014332/angular-5-with-cachestorage

Comment: added an answer on the dup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52083423/2258093